# Patch SUPEE-10975 can't be installed successfully

Tags: patches, magento1.9.2.4

I have a Magento 1.9.2.4 instance and I am trying to install patch SUPEE-10975 so that I can install patch SUPEE-11086.

When I try to install, I get the following message:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Group/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Template/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/BlockController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/GroupController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/SitemapController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/BackupController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Model/Observer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Model/Zend.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api2/Product/Image/Rest/Admin/V1.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Media/Api.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
Hunk #2 succeeded at 387 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.6.1.2-1.6.0.6.1.3.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Customer.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 280 (offset -9 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Customer/Address.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 281 (offset -22 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/sql/payment_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.1.1-1.6.0.0.1.2.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/Block/Send.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/files.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/captcha.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/sharing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 36.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/sendfriend/send.phtml
checking file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
checking file app/etc/modules/Mage_Captcha.xml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Wishlist.csv
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.min.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.min.map
```

I checked my applied.patches.list to make sure the previous patch, SUPEE-10888, was installed, and it looks like it was. My applied.patches.list is too long to post, so here is about half of it (the most recent half):

```
2018-07-03 14:33:35 UTC | SUPEE-10752_CE_v1.9.2.4 | CE_1.9.2.4 | v1 | 21a859a3088f1c667802d48b1637144c3a040442 | Tue Jun 5 02:11:41 2018 +0300 | ce-1.9.2.4-dev
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Composite/Fieldset/Options.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Datetime.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Wysiwyg/ImagesController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/StoreController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Tree.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Api/Resource/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 366 (offset 26 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Abstract/Backend/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups/Backend/Freemethod.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups/Backend/OriginShipment.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups/Backend/Type.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Validate/EmailAddress.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/shipping/ups.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/catalog/product/links.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
patching file cron.php
patching file js/tiny_mce/plugins/media/.htaccess
patching file lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php


2018-11-05 15:42:14 UTC | SUPEE-10888_CE_v1.9.2.4 | CE_1.9.2.4 | v1 | 145cee001262628c9fe50c99816f0a54ee37a5ea | Fri Aug 31 10:50:32 2018 +0300 | ce-1.9.2.4-dev
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Api/Resource/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.4.1.2-1.6.2.0.4.1.3.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/shipment/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/multishipping/item/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/template/email/account_password_reset_confirmation.html
patching file app/locale/en_US/template/email/admin_new_user_notification.html
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/enterprise/images/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg


2018-11-05 16:15:05 UTC | SUPEE-10888_CE_v1.9.2.4 | CE_1.9.2.4 | v1 | 145cee001262628c9fe50c99816f0a54ee37a5ea | Fri Aug 31 10:50:32 2018 +0300 | ce-1.9.2.4-dev | REVERTED
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Api/Resource/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.4.1.2-1.6.2.0.4.1.3.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/shipment/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/multishipping/item/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/template/email/account_password_reset_confirmation.html
patching file app/locale/en_US/template/email/admin_new_user_notification.html
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/enterprise/images/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg


2018-11-05 16:17:13 UTC | SUPEE-10888_CE_v1.9.2.4 | CE_1.9.2.4 | v1 | 145cee001262628c9fe50c99816f0a54ee37a5ea | Fri Aug 31 10:50:32 2018 +0300 | ce-1.9.2.4-dev
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Api/Resource/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.4.1.2-1.6.2.0.4.1.3.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/sales/order/shipment/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/multishipping/item/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/sales/order/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/creditmemo/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/invoice/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/template/email/account_password_reset_confirmation.html
patching file app/locale/en_US/template/email/admin_new_user_notification.html
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/enterprise/images/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg
```

Any idea what my problem might be?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222373/magento-patch-supee-10975-can%C2%B4t-be-applied-successfully

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone, I was able to solve this by changing a line in app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml:

I had replaced

```
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js</script></action>
```

with

```
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js</script></action>
```

to address a jquery version PCI compliance issue. Changing the line back enabled the patch to be applied successfully:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
```

Muhammad Hasham pointed me in the right direction by linking to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222373/magento-patch-supee-10975-can%C2%B4t-be-applied-successfully, where the I realized that the issue was in the file mentioned in the message before "Hunk #1 FAILED at 36." I then inspected app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml and realized that I had made a change in the file, making the patch unable to apply.

This page was also helpful:
https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-10975-without-ssh/

thanks again.